# How to make RowLayout wrap its content?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I am using `RowLayout` for thumbnails of images. All the thumbnails are being displayed in one row only. How can I make them to display efficiently in multiple rows upon resizing?

Comment: Your answer is quite good. Thanx alot dear. But my problem was something else, it was not related to wrap.

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer then?

Comment: Your answer is helpful. I just came to know the feature of wrap in RowLayout because of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find it in the documentation of [`RowLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FRowLayout.html).

What you're looking for is `RowLayout#wrap`:

> wrap specifies whether a control will be wrapped to the next row if there is insufficient space on the current row. **The default value is true**.

Since the default is `true`, it should already wrap...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
    layout.wrap = true;
    shell.setLayout(layout);

    Image image = new Image(display, "star.png");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setImage(image);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(200, 100);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();

    image.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this before resizing:

[image]

And after resizing:

[image]